# How to use UIScrollView to switch between UIViews

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

How would I build multiple `UIViews` with multiple subviews and switch between them using a `UIScrollView`? I would appreciate anyone who can upload some code. I am a complete noob withe the iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would "tile" the UIViews in the UIScrollView, then implement some kind of paging or "snap-to" mechanism. Listen on the appropriate notifications from the scroll view, then whenever scrolling finishes, just programmatically align the scroll view to the boundaries of one of your tiled UIViews.

Alternately, look at using [UIPageControl](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to implement this kind of behavior. The Weather app is a good example.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done that, but I saw one example at the app development center. I'm adding the corresponding link:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Scrolling/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008023

I hope it helps

Regards 
Alejandra :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Page Control](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/PageControl/) sample.  This uses the *UIScrollView* paging functionality to do horizontal scrolling between multiple *UIView* pages.

This demo also has a *UIPageControl* that updates as you flick between the horizontally scrolled views.